# Centering an input button in CSS on Google Chrome for Mac

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to center input fields and buttons ( tags) in an html form. I'm doing that with auto left and right margins. That works fine on most browsers but doesn't centre on Chrome for Mac (it does on Chromium for Linux):

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form style="width: 300px; display: block; text-align: center; background: red;">
      <input value="Centre" type="submit" style="display: block; margin: 10px auto; background: green;" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect to see the button centered within the form but on Chrome Mac I see it on the left hand side. If I give it an explicit width the button centers, or if I use another form element like a textarea, but those aren't very satisfactory solutions.

Comment: If the behaviour differs from operating system to operating system, then I think you're encountering a bug with Chrome/Webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the display block from the button;

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form style="width: 300px; display: block; text-align: center; background: red;">
      <input value="Centre" type="submit" style=" margin: 10px auto; background:none; border:none; background-color:green;" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

try this.

Comment: That works but the actual pages I have are more complicated and have several inputs one after another (some text fields, some buttons) which I would like to have on new lines. Should I just make them 'display: inline;' and add <br /> tags between, is there a more elegant solution? Also can you explain why that works?

Comment: <br /> will help yeh, or you can just wrap em in ul -> li. and use css to get the desired effect.